# How to get null value column when using union two dataframe using java8

Tags: java, apache-spark

df1

```
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  SEQ_NO|  ATTR1|ATTR2|ATTR3|ATTR4|ATTR5|
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   75745|821932| 49683| 9683|    T| null|
|      14|821932| 49683| 9683|    T| null|
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

df2

```
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|  SEQ_NO|  ATTR1|ATTR2|ATTR3|ATTR5|
+--------+-------+-----+-----+ ----+
|32523532|821932| 49683| 9683| null|
|    3920|821932| 49683| 9683| null|
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
```

expected output

```
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  SEQ_NO|  ATTR1|ATTR2|ATTR3|ATTR4|ATTR5|
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   75745|821932| 49683| 9683|    T| null|
|      14|821932| 49683| 9683|    T| null|
|32523532|821932| 49683| 9683|    T| null|
|    3920|821932| 49683| 9683|    T| null|
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+

Dataset<Row> df3 = spark.read.json(df1.toJSON.union(df2.toJSON))
```

but output is coming as below

```
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|  SEQ_NO|  ATTR1|ATTR2|ATTR3|ATTR4|
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|   75745|821932| 49683| 9683|    T|
|      14|821932| 49683| 9683|    T|
|32523532|821932| 49683| 9683|    T|
|    3920|821932| 49683| 9683|    T| 
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Pls help to get expected output.  ATTR5 column value is null in both dataframe.. when doing union, it is not getting union. is any option to get null contain column as well. Using java8 with Spark

Comment: do you have ATTR4 in dataframe 2? which you are expecting in Output

Comment: use `join` instead of `union`

Comment: Would a Scala piece of code be helpful ? You need to reconciliate your schemas first

Comment: Dataset<Row> df_util_6 = spark.read().json(df_util_5.toJSON().join(df_util_4.toJSON()));

Comment: please send me java code

Answer (score 0):

Scala solution to solve your problem, should be reproductible in Java :

```
df1.show()
+------+------+-----+
|SEQ_NO| ATTR1|ATTR5|
+------+------+-----+
| 75745|821932| null|
+------+------+-----+
df2.show()
+--------+------+-------+-----+
|  SEQ_NO| ATTR1|  ATTR2|ATTR5|
+--------+------+-------+-----+
|32523532|821932|1331321| null|
+--------+------+-------+-----+
```

Here we're gonna create a projection using the Dataframe value when defined or infer a null column when missing from Dataframe schema, for both Dataframes before the union.

```
val allColumns = (df1.schema.fields.toSeq ++ df2.schema.fields).distinct
val projection = {df: DataFrame => allColumns.map{c => if(df.columns contains c.name) col(c.name) else lit(null).cast(c.dataType).as(c.name)}}

df1.select(projection(df1):_*)
  .union(df2.select(projection(df2):_*))
  .show()
+--------+------+-----+-------+
|SEQ_NO  |ATTR1 |ATTR5|ATTR2  |
+--------+------+-----+-------+
|75745   |821932|null |null   |
|32523532|821932|null |1331321|
+--------+------+-----+-------+
```

Edit : Here's a working Java version

```
public static Column[] projection(LinkedHashSet<StructField> allColumns, Dataset<Row> df){
    return allColumns.stream().map(c -> Arrays.asList(df.columns()).contains(c.name())? new Column(c.name()):new Column(new Literal(null, DataTypes.StringType)).as(c.name())).toArray(Column[]::new);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    SparkSession ss = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("zaeae").getOrCreate();

    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>(1);
    l1.add("{\"SEQ_NO\": 75745, \"ATTR1\": 821932, \"ATTR5\":null}");
    JavaRDD<String> parallelize1 = new JavaSparkContext(ss.sparkContext()).parallelize(l1, 1);
    Dataset<Row> df1 = ss.read().json(parallelize1);


    List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>(1);
    l2.add("{\"SEQ_NO\": 32523532, \"ATTR1\": 821932, \"ATTR2\":1331321, \"ATTR5\":null}");
    JavaRDD<String> parallelize2 = new JavaSparkContext(ss.sparkContext()).parallelize(l2, 1);
    Dataset<Row> df2 = ss.read().json(parallelize2);


    final List<StructField> unionAllColumns = new ArrayList();
    unionAllColumns.addAll(Arrays.asList(df1.schema().fields()));
    unionAllColumns.addAll(Arrays.asList(df2.schema().fields()));

    LinkedHashSet<StructField> allColumns = new LinkedHashSet<StructField>(unionAllColumns);

    df1.select(projection(allColumns, df1))
      .union(df2.select(projection(allColumns, df2)))
      .show();
}

+------+-----+--------+-------+
| ATTR1|ATTR5|  SEQ_NO|  ATTR2|
+------+-----+--------+-------+
|821932| null|   75745|   null|
|821932| null|32523532|1331321|
+------+-----+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks.. Please convert into java code.. i don't know scala. it is expected result.

Comment: Hi @Tamil, just added a java version